# C++ converting double to long

Tags: c++, double, long-integer

I used `pow(double base, double exponent)` in my program, how can I convert the answer to `long` data type?

Comment: You can just cast it - `(long)pow(base, exp)`

Comment: Why do you want to convert to long first of all ? Also c++ provide ceiling and floor , if you need nearest less than  and greater than number

Comment: 'cause my data type for input is long.

Comment: assigning a value to a long variable automatically cast it to `long`

Answer (score 8):

Just use one of the following statements (depending on your personal requirements):

1. `lround(pow(base, exp));` (nearest number to the result)
2. `floor(pow(base, exp));` (nearest number less than the result)
3. `ceil(pow(base, exp));` (nearest number larger than the result)

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot.

Comment: No, in my pc, I tried it and it rounded the result up too. Maybe it depends on the compiler

Comment: Watch what happens with 1 if provided a negative number.

Comment: @TanmoyKrishnaDas if your compiler rounds to nearest when casting floating point to integer, then it's not following the standard. `lround` is good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an actual conversion from double to long.

After some research, casting actually does the trick:

```
double myDouble = 12.345;
long myTruncatedLong = (long) myDouble;
```

myTruncatedLong will be 12.